# How can I upload an iCal file to a user's calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I tried to find solutions on how to save a iCal file to the user's calendar, but I just couldn't find it. I found things like write an iCal file and read one, but I want it to be Pushed to the user's calendar. How can I do so?

Goal I want to archieve: Provide an url of a iCal file that I want to be imported into the user's calendar. How can I do so?

Example url: https://abc.xyz.nl/api/v2/ical?access_token=accestoken&startWeekOffset=-1&endWeekOffset=2&valid=true&user=me

**EDIT:**
How can I subscribe an user to that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't 'push' a file to a users calendar.  You can provide a ics url or a 'add to google' type link but it is entirely up to the user how the deal with that file and what calendar application they use to deal with it

For example: I would NEVER want to 'import' your url (a once off event, no updates will be done) into my main calendar.  I'd happily import a single event to save me typing it in.  If it's a url I'd prefer to 'subscribe' to it as a separate calendar that I can unsubscribe to at a later stage and that I will see updates on while I am subscribed to it.

Comment: Well... I agree. How can I let the user "subscribe" to it then?

Comment: To offer a calendar for subscription, one simply provides a public link to the ics feed or file.  The feed/file should have a content type of text/calendar, end in a .ics suffix and contain valid RFC5545 event definitions in a valid format.  You could also consider offering links to apple/outlook/google etc pages that describe how to subscribe to the url.

Answer (score 0):

I found a issue that seems to show that it is not possible out of the box:
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=210

So i guess you have to parse the file by yourself and create Google Calendar Objects out of it.

Or you use the CalDav API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide that supports Icalendar. But i guess there you have to make sure the file has not to many events.